# BitBucket - Please make sure you have the correct access rights - newly created custom named Key not 'used'

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

#### Custom named SSH key is not used by BitBucket repo's.

I have been experiencing issues with BitBucket SSH authentication on one server.

Answers here on SO recommends removing the key and recreating a new key.

I followed this article to create a new key:
[Atlassian setup an SSH key](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/)

So I have created a new key (custom key name):  `/home/username/.ssh/id_bitbucket_rsa`
(a `./ssh/id_rsa` default key already exists so I didn't want other applications that use this key to break)

```
$ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa): /home/username/.ssh/id_bitbucket_rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/username/.ssh/id_bitbucket_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /home/username/.ssh/id_bitbucket_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
```

The article mentions to 'add' the key like this:

```
:~/.ssh$ eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 4661
:~/.ssh$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_bitbucket_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/username/.ssh/id_bitbucket_rsa:
Identity added: /home/username/.ssh/id_bitbucket_rsa (username@host)
```

Then testing the key seems to **confirm that the new key I applied on BitBucket account settings works**:

This in `~` home folder:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

However, trying to do `git fetch` to see if it works:  **It doesn't prompt for a password which I added onto the new Key.**

```
~:
git fetch
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

There is no password prompt that appears, so this tells me this repo possibly still uses `id_rsa`.

Inside the repo folder:

```
 ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
```

How do I get SSH or BitBucket repo to refresh to *use the newly created custom named key*?
The article doesn't mention anything extra to 'force use the custom key'....

Comment: You can add `-v[vv]` to `ssh [-T]` command to get more info on what's happening. You need to tell your ssh client to use the new key?: https://superuser.com/a/232406

Comment: I ran `ssh -T` as you saw in the different folders, giving me two results.  I will have a look at the link to see what the BitBucket article missed to mention, also couldn't really find anything on SO.

Comment: Thank you, that answer was almost it, the config method was the way to go (I had no `config` file in my folder), but curiously I had to add `User git` as well for the config method works.  Do you mind giving an official answer here so that I can mark answer?  Thanks again.